# How to put default value on Multi select using reactjs and Material UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

How can I set a default value on Multiple selection (CHIP) using reactjs and material ui? I search all over the internet but i cant find any documentation related to my problem,

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import OutlinedInput from '@mui/material/OutlinedInput';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';
import Chip from '@mui/material/Chip';

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
const MenuProps = {
  PaperProps: {
    style: {
      maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
      width: 250,
    },
  },
};

const names = [
  'Oliver Hansen',
  'Van Henry',
  'April Tucker',
];

function getStyles(name, personName, theme) {
  return {
    fontWeight:
      personName.indexOf(name) === -1
        ? theme.typography.fontWeightRegular
        : theme.typography.fontWeightMedium,
  };
}

export default function MultipleSelectChip() {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const {
      target: { value },
    } = event;
    setPersonName(
      // On autofill we get a stringified value.
      typeof value === 'string' ? value.split(',') : value,
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 300 }}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-multiple-chip-label">Chip</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-multiple-chip-label"
          id="demo-multiple-chip"
          multiple
          value={personName}
          onChange={handleChange}
          input={<OutlinedInput id="select-multiple-chip" label="Chip" />}
          renderValue={(selected) => (
            <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap', gap: 0.5 }}>
              {selected.map((value) => (
                <Chip key={value} label={value} />
              ))}
            </Box>
          )}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
        >
          {names.map((name) => (
            <MenuItem
              key={name}
              value={name}
              style={getStyles(name, personName, theme)}
            >
              {name}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

> How can I set a default value on Multiple selection (CHIP) using
> reactjs and material ui? I search all over the internet but i cant
> find any documentation related to my problem, How can I set a default
> value on Multiple selection (CHIP) using reactjs and material ui? I
> search all over the internet but i cant find any documentation related
> to my problem, How can I set a default value on Multiple selection
> (CHIP) using reactjs and material ui? I search all over the internet
> but i cant find any documentation related to my problem,

Answer (score 1):

Add initial values in the state variable

```
const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState(['Oliver Hansen']); // or [names[0]]
```